# Check if Input is in Conda Environment

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a bash file which I need to include validation check. Basically, the purpose of the file is to accept an input and activate the virtual environment. 
Which is done with this line:

```
source activate $1
```

However, I need to check if the input is a valid conda environment. 
When I do the following command:

```
conda env list
```

It will return:

```
# conda environments:
#
py2713                   /opt/anaconda2/envs/py2713
py341                    /opt/anaconda2/envs/py341
py345                    /opt/anaconda2/envs/py345
root                  *  /opt/anaconda2
```

I.e the script must check if the input is either `py2713`, `py341`, `py345` or `root`. If it is not in the list of environments, it should return a message and exit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following can be done to check if the right env is passed into the file
You would run the shell file with the following command

```
sh file.sh py2713
```

The file.sh would contain:

```
ENVS=$(conda env list | awk '{print $1}' )
if [[ $ENVS = *"$1"* ]]; then
   source activate $1
else 
   echo "Error: Please provide a valid virtual environment. For a list of valid virtual environment, please see 'conda env list' "
   exit
fi;
```